# List item callout error "TypeError: b is undefined"

Tags: sharepoint-2013, callout

I've created a column in Visual Studio with the Callout option set to "TRUE" :

```
<Field ID="{1c31ceba-0f02-4906-a8d4-f5158d6d159e}" Name="myColumn" Type="Text" DisplayName="My title" Required="TRUE" CalloutMenu="TRUE" />
```

I use this field in a list template which is used to create a list instance. I create a new item in that list.

Then, in Firefox 26, when I create a new item in that list and click on the callout "..." button, the content of the callout is not displayed and instead the following error message shows up: "TypeError: b is undefined".

On Chrome 31, the error message says: "TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined".

In IE 10 it works fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

EG